# What patterns/rules are used to search tweets?

Tags: twitter

**TL;DR What are the rules used by twitter to determine whether a tweet matches a certain query, and how can those be replicated?**

Hello,
I am using the Twitter API (both v1 and v2, long story) for the development of an academic tool for research purposes.

I need to be able to know if a given string would match a twitter query. A simple regex keyword match wouldn't work as it is my understanding that they are tokenized so that looking for `Pied Piper` can return `#PiedPiper`, `@piedpiper_official`, `Pied Piper`, `#pied piper`, etc.

I think the problem requires a deeper understanding of how the search works "under the hood" (not how to use the API, but rather understanding the matching process and rules used by twitter to determine which tweets are returned by the query). After days of research, I have found nothing.

Please let me know if you know any details. As small as they might seem, they can help a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Concatenate tokens, lowercase, then match.

```py
#! /usr/bin/env python3
import re  ##  docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html

##  only grab AlphaNumeric chars, skip # @ and whitespace
tokens = re .findall( '\w+', 'Pied Piper' )

print( tokens )
```

> ['Pied', 'Piper']

```py
##  concatenate & lowercase
lowercase = '' .join( tokens ) .lower()

##  www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_join.asp
print( lowercase )
```

> piedpiper